# I can't find the jungle temple in my large world

Tags: terraria

[image]

I've been searching for a [Jungle Temple](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Jungle_Temple) for quite a while now. I have reached right to left and top to bottom of the jungle and it still hasn't shown up. I don't know how large it is, but I don't think it's that small and I'm worried that my world has spawned without one.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no real answer possible based on the information offered: we can give general tips and conjecture, but the question isn't asking for either.

Answer (score 2):

You should look deeper. The temple is usually closer to hell than you think. Here is an example on a large world.

[image]